# Meaning of 图像 in this sentence: 图片可作为单独的图像

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

> 500万像素，带LED灯（图片可作为单独的图像）

This is the description of the resolution of a [digital camera](http://www.heikadq.com/col.jsp?id=125).

So it says 5 million pixels and an LED light included, and I don't really understand what it says between parentheses.

图片 is a photo so it is "a photo can become individual 图像" but I'm not sure which definition of 图像 works in this sentence. Photo can be an image? Photo can be a video?

Comment: I think its only mean can save as a picture not just record video, its not a good sentence.

Comment: So does that mean it can save as picture and video? Or picture only and no video?

Comment: At next row it says".jpg（含全温度数据）&   全温度红外视频 & .jpg可见光图片" the middle of it should be video? So I guess it could get both, if you wanna buy it, you could contact the seller or the company to understand the details.

Comment: To be honest, as a native, I do not understand what it means ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 图片：image
- 图像：image

If there is not a context, the two words are interchangeable. But the context makes it clear.

The product of the page is a **thermal camera**. And you know thermal images are special kind of image which shows the temperature instead of color. But the row you are looking at is as below.

> 内置数码相机  |  500万像素，带LED灯（图片可作为单独的图像）

Translation: Digital camera embedded, 5 million pixel, LED light source embedded (image can be used as separated image)

This row mentions that in addition to the **thermal camera**, it has another "digital camera" inside. "数码相机", "digital camera", is one complete word means an **ordinary consumer digital camera**, and in the current situation, it means ordinary camera that capture **RGB color**.

Then the meaning of 图片可作为单独的图像（image can be used as separated image） is clear. It is short for "（RGB相机的）图片可以作为单独的图像（，与温度图像分离）" （RGB image can be used as separated image from thermal image.）. You can view the RGB image only without the thermal information if necessary.

In the example below (source from the link provided in question description), the left one is the thermal image and the right one is the RGB image form that "Digital Camera".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

图片可作为单独的图像

I suppose you need to know something about digital photography to understand that sentence.

图片 = video frame

可作为单独的 = could be made into or saved as a single

图像 = image or photo.

So, the technical English equivalent would be "the video frame(s) could be made into or saved as a single photo image"

Here is an example instruction on how it's done:-

"To extract and save a single video frame as an image:

```
Do one of the following:

    While the video is playing, click the Pause button at the frame you want to save.
    On the progress slider, move the pointer to display the frame you want to save"
```

Now try and translate the above instructions into Chinese, whether modern or ancient?